# MySQL trigger select correct value for inserted rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need help building a trigger in MySql.
I have an 'employee' table structured as follows:

```
id
first name
role
```

I would like to create a trigger to automatically assign the role to the new employee inserted, choosing the one that is currently less present in the table.
Ex: there are two cleaners and 1 driver only. By inserting a field, the role of driver is automatically assigned.
My problem is not the trigger structure but only in the query to select the correct role.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_employees
BEFORE INSERT 
ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.role_id = ( SELECT role_id 
                    FROM employees
                    GROUP BY role_id
                    ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This trigger will select one Job, that has the least number of persons assigned and add it to the role column

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE worktable (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `first name` VARCHAR(5),
  `role` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO worktable
  (`id`, `first name`, `role`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'test1', 'Cleaner'),
  ('2', 'test2', 'Cleaner'),
  ('3', 'test3', 'Driver'),
  ('4', 'test4', 'Dishwasher');

 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE  TRIGGER `worktable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `worktable` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET NEW.`role` := (SELECT `role` FROM worktable GROUP BY `role` ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO worktable
  (`id`, `first name`, `role`)
VALUES
  ('5', 'test5', '');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM worktable;

| id  | first name | role       |
| --- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1   | test1      | Cleaner    |
| 2   | test2      | Cleaner    |
| 3   | test3      | Driver     |
| 4   | test4      | Dishwasher |
| 5   | test5      | Driver     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/5)